# Unusable textbox and combobox in windows forms

Tags: windows, forms

I have a problem with a form, textbox and combobox are unusable after some execution.
My application interacts with a cad program and after some operations it simply breaks.
Controls just shows one color, gray or black (after minimize and restore).
tried to debug but no error is thrown.
the only thing particular I do (in the form) is the add and remove controls from a panel during the execution.

Trackbar and datagrid are still fine.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself.
Instead of having a single panel and adding removing controls on it I've created multiple panels and show one at time.
I consider it a work around because I should be able to dinamically add or remove controls.
With the new method, crossing fingers, the problem is disappeared.